# $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module , and $N$ be a submodule of $M$ ; is it possible to have a meaning for $Ann(M)/N$ as an ideal?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module, and $N$ be a submodule of $M$; is it possible to have a meaning for $Ann(M)/N$ as an ideal? (I ask this question due to its use in the third line in the proof in [this paper](http://www.epmath.ir/BooksPapers/a002.pdf). Does the author mean the ideal to be $\{a\in R:aM \subseteq N\}$? Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the true statement is $Ann (M/N)=p,$ not $Ann (M)/N=p.$ Assume that

> $Ann (M/N)=p.$

Now $a\notin p$ means $a(M/N)\neq 0$, which means $aM\nsubseteq‎ N$. So $N+aM$ strictly contains $N$. (Similar argument is true for $b$ instead of $a$.) Hence $N+aM$ and $N+bM$ are both finitely generated.

Comment: That is to say $(N:M):=\{x\in R | xM\subseteq N\}$ , right ?

Comment: yes, $Ann (M/N)=\{x\in R | x(M/ N)=0(=N)\}= \{x\in R | xM\subseteq N\}=(N:M)$

Comment: It is really troublesome to get some printing error in some published paper in AMM . Anyway , thanks a lot

Comment: you are welcome.